# Voltage sense multi range - how to switch with no voltage drop

Tags: voltage-measurement

I have an application where I need to measure precisely (<0.05%) a voltage level which can be from 1V up to 500V.

To do so, I use several voltage divider that are then multiplexed to a

ADC.

However, in order to keep the current through the voltage dividers as small as possible, I need to have some sort of switch mechanism, on the high side, that is able to withstand 500V and has minimum voltage drop.

The current through the channels are in the order of 10mA.

I checked if that could be done with P-Channel MOSFET, but the Rds on is in the 30ohm range which would introduce an error of about 0.06%.

Another option would be to use small relays, but I would prefer to avoid mechanical devices.

Is there any other options possible ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFsKHz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: did you plot out how the error is biased? I'd assume that the mosfets will bias the result more than introduce errors. Then calibration will get you your accuracy back

Comment: @ratchetfreak I believe Rds is temperature dependent and might change during lifetime as well. 0.05% is the absolute accuracy, including signal treatement, ADC, references, so I need to keep room for the rest.

Comment: That high of a precision will need regular calibration anyway (because your DAC is going to drift over time as well), that solves the lifetime issue, a thermocouple (and maybe small heating element to stabilize the temperature) will solve the temperature issue.

Comment: Also a diagramm, how it suposed to work, would be helpful to understand, what you want to achieve. And also what the MOSFET is supposed to do.

Comment: 500:1 (@0.05% accuracy) is a lot of dynamic range. What value is the dropping resistor for 500V?

Comment: 390k / 180ohm @SpehroPefhany

Comment: You could use NMOS on the high side. No need to use PMOS. You will just need some type of charge pump driver IC to turn on the NMOS. That will be cheap compared to your 0.01% resistor divider.

Comment: And it is true that you can calibrate for the AVERAGE Rds to reduce error. Then you will only pay the penalty for the variability of the Rds, not the whole Rds.

Comment: Also, you could use higher value resistors to reduce the current, then the Rds would not matter. Use a precision op-amp to buffer the voltage so that the sense circuit does not load the resistor divider.

Comment: @mkeith I would need to have the charge pump feeding from the sense line, it's not ideal. I could have a isolated DC/DC with some isolation logic, but I would have to tie it up to the sense line as well, and I'm worried this will introduce noice, It's 16bit 400khz measurement system and noise is not trivial to handle.

Comment: 400 kHz. Jeez. And I guess it needs to be DC-coupled, also?

Comment: @mkeith yes it's absolute DC measurement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> measure precisely (<0.05%) a voltage level which can be from 1V up to 500V

Ouch! Given these extreme requirements it's probably worth reconsidering mechanical relays. Replacing the PMOS's in your circuit with relays probably works out to be the easiest way to go. That's why you often hear lab equivalent with large dynamic ranges "click" their way through the range.

An alternative would be to hang two resistive dividers off each switch, change the resistance slightly in the second branch, and measure both. For example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYJm00.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Then you have:

$$
V_a = V_{sens}\frac{R_{2a}}{R_{2a}+R_{1a}+R_{ds}}
$$

and

$$
V_b = V_{sens}\frac{R_{2b}}{R_{2b}+R_{1b}+R_{ds}}
$$

Two equations, two unknowns (\$V_{sens}\$ and \$R_{ds}\$), so rearrange:

$$
R_{2a}V_{sens} - V_aR_{ds} = V_a(R_{2a}+R_{1a})
$$
$$
R_{2b}V_{sens} - V_bR_{ds} = V_b(R_{2b}+R_{1b})
$$

Solve simultaneously and you'll have \$V_{sens}\$ and can discard \$R_{ds}\$.

You'll need a lot of very high precision resistors, but at least your switch voltage drop can be neglected.

Answer (score 1):

Your maximum dropping value of 390K can probably be used for all ranges from 1V to 500V by switching load resistors on the low side and reading the voltage differentially. By reading the voltage differentially the effect of the switch resistance is eliminated provided  you stay within the common mode voltage range of the ADC.

For example, in the below circuit, analog switches 1 and 3 would be closed for reading with R2 and the others open.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXKZWm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You will need to calculate the leakages of the analog switches to ensure that it does not spoil your accuracy specification, especially at high Ta.

---

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fudLrv.png)</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately, on the 1V range, the current would be 2.56uA, and I need to have minimum 25uA through the voltage divider to ensure linearity on the measurement circuit.

Comment: Can  you add a buffer? Or add a dummy load if that is the problem?

Comment: I could add a buffer, although the acquisition circuit is already done and I know it works, this would need to rework the acquisition design which I would rather avoid. Another issue of this circuit is in case there is a software bug with the switch it would send 500V right to the ADC. A zener to prevent this would have too much leakage.

Comment: The current would be limited to 1.2mA which is easily handled by a clamp (eg. a low leakage diode to a biased zener) or even the protection diodes in the buffer amplifier. Anyway, you could use your original concept with much lower Rds(on) MOSFETs but you'd have to load the input with all the gate drive circuits in parallel and you'd need something like  a -10V rail to both switch 0-1V and handle 500V. Not impossible but the loading will be significant.

Comment: The problem is the leakage current of zener or similar clamping method which will alter the linearity since it's on several tens of uA.

Comment: See a couple low leakage clamp circuits above.

Comment: Typically leakage on a zener is about 50nA, which represents a 0.2% error on the circuit with a 25uA current on the voltage divider, and this is non-linear to the voltage so it becomes an issue to calibrate.

Comment: I start to think the relay perhaps remains the best solution.

Comment: There are fA clamping solution. Your idea is valid although there is quite a bit to implement and at this point the pro/cons the relay still win in my situation. If there are no better answers I'll accept yours.

Comment: It's pretty common to use bistable telecom style relays for this kind of application.Low thermal EMF is another benefit  and the parasitic capacitances are much lower than most other solutions. But you still have the clamp issue.